# two's complement

Tags: binary, int, representation, twos-complement

As far as I know, the two's complement algo is:

> 1.Represent the decimal in binary.
>   2.Inverse all bits.
>   3.Add 1 to the last bit.

For the number `3`, which its representation is: `0000000000000011` the result of the two's complement would be `1111111111111101` which is `-3`.
So far so good.
But for the number `2` which its representation is `0000000000000010` the result of the two's complement would be `1111111111111101`, which isn't 2 but -3.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0...0010 // 2
1...1101 // Flip the bits
1...1110 // Add one
```

It works for negative too:

```
1...1110 // -2
0...0001 // Flip the bits
0...0010 // Add one
```

Comment: Thank you, I had a mistake in the addition of the 1.

Comment: @pst I don't know what you're saying

Comment: I have another mini-question.
What is the difference between my algorithm of negating a number and scanning the number from right to left and complementing all the bits after the first appearance of a 1?

Comment: @Lior I'm not sure it would work but you could try it out with pen and paper. Even if it did I assume the circuitry required would be far more that a simple bit inversion and add, which is very quick.

Comment: Ok, thank you :)
If you want to read more about the "alternative conversion process" (as written in wikipedia) :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: @Lior: It is mathematically same. The effect of adding 1 in the 3rd step will re-flip low bits to zero or more zeroes (`0`) preceded by a one (`1`); so instead of flipping everything and then reflipping low bits by addition of `1`, you can just flip those that would flip anyway, and not flip those that would be reflipped by addition. The algorithm (up to first `1` from the right) tells you which bits would be affected by the step 3. In case of `2` you had, adding `1` to `1101` flips to `1110`, so the last `10` is the nonflipping portion from original `0010`; everything else to the left flips.

Answer (score 3):

For your code you might have needed to do 2's complement: i just wanted to throw this out there(a **quicker** way of getting a negative binary) :

2's complement is very useful for finding the value of a binary, however I thought of a much more concise way of solving such a problem(never seen anyone else publish it):

take a binary, for example: 1101 which is [assuming that space "1" is the sign] equal to **-3**.

using 2's complement we would do this...flip 1101 to 0010...add 0001 + 0010 ===> gives us 0011. 0011 in positive binary = 3. therefore 1101 = **-3**!

***What I realized:***

instead of all the flipping and adding, you can just do the basic method for solving for a positive binary(lets say 0101) is (2<sup>3</sup> * 0) + (2<sup>2</sup> * 1) + (2<sup>1</sup> * 0) + (2<sup>0</sup> * 1) = 5.

**Do exactly the same concept with a negative!(with a small twist)**

take 1101, for example:

for the first number instead of 2<sup>3</sup> * 1 = **8** , do -(2<sup>3</sup> * 1) = **-8**.

then continue as usual, doing **-8** + (2<sup>2</sup> * 1) + (2<sup>1</sup> * 0) + (2<sup>0</sup> * 1) = **-3**

Hope that may help!

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

Skipping step 3 for your second example (or misunderstanding it).

`1111111111111101` is ones' complement of `2` (i.e. result of step 1 and 2); you need to add 1 - not to the last bit (as in binary digit), but to the last result (as in, what you get from step 2).

Comment: Thank you, I had a mistake in the addition of the 1.