# What does it mean to express a bit string as a two’s complement quantity in decimal?

Tags: binary, decimal, twos-complement

Original question: Express the bit string 11001110 as a decimal quantity, first interpreted as an unsigned quantity, and second interpreted as a two’s complement quantity.

So, for the bit string 11001110, its complement is 00110001, which is 49 in decimal, right?

But I am not sure what the question is asking. Is the bit string 11001110 is already a complemented version? Or am I asked to find its complement and convert it into decimal?

Second, 11001110 is 206 in decimal; since two's complement uses the most significant bit as a sign bit, then 206 cannot be represented in two's complement right (due to overflow, assuming only 8-bit used)? It will be negative. But 00110001 the most significant bit is 0, which means the quantity is positive? I am confused...

Answer (score 0):

#### Two's Complement

To get the twos-complement of a number, invert the bits and add 1. If you want verification of your answer, use an online converter like [this one](https://www.exploringbinary.com/twos-complement-converter/). Keep in mind that the width of your twos complement can make the [overflow bit drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805087/how-is-overflow-detected-in-twos-complement).

There are various stack overflow questions that also address two's complement like

- [twos complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735443/twos-complement)
- [What is 2s complement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement)